# Data scraping from a list split into pages

Tags: web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a list of Sports venues from these two pages:
openplay.co.uk 
and mylocalpitch.com
in the second one, the search results for venues are split into pages of 10 each. Now when I run a scraper on it, it looks at the first ten search results, but not the ones that are 'hidden' in the other pages.
I was using a scrape tool called import.io and it failed miserably. Is there a tool that can do it? Will I need to write my own?

Comment: There is a separate site for software recommendations - hence the downvotes. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick API for you to the site and managed to get more than 20 pages. If you visit the link below:

https://import.io/data/mine/?id=01ac4491-e40a-4e2b-a427-c057692e3d96

you can see a button called next page that should get you the other search results after the 10th result.

Let me know how you get on.